# Sbt console run from different package

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am curious if there is any possibility to tell the sbt console `paste` command to execute in a specific package.

So far I read about using `:paste -raw` but that did not do the trick.

My problem is due to the nice use of sparks default parameters writable which are only internally available in sparks private API I choose to place my custom estimator into sparks namespace. This works fine when run locally but the great and interactive experience of the scala repl is sort of destroyed as I cannot run my estimator which resides in organizing.apache.spark.ml

Comment: `-raw` is not scala 2.10, only 2.11+.

Comment: I think `:pate -raw` is the right way. What errors are you getting when you try that?

Comment: Actually 2.11 suits me well.

Comment: `paste -raw` runs through just fine, The problem was I needed to reference the fully qualified namespace `new org.apache.spark.ml.MyThing()`. Is there a possibility to "import" that transformer to make a reference of `MyThing` work .

Answer (score 1):

One option is to take your estimator, use `sbt assembly` to turn it into a jar and then to upload that jar when you run a spark shell or run with spark-submit. Is there a reason why you need to use the spark namespace? Why not use your own name space?

Comment: as I tried to outline: Apache Spark 2.02 (current version) does not open up all the great helper methods for pipeline / Estimator serialization. Spark`s `DefaultParamsWriter` is very neat.  `sbt package / assembly`is an option, but it is not as nice / interactive.

Comment: Something is wrong here, there's got to be a better way to achieve what you want in a legit way, you're essentially hacking spark internals and Spark is not fond of being tampered with.